# Count unique values per day, if timestamp has hours

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have dataset:

```
timestamp               event   user
2020-04-28 20:07:55.503 log_in  john
2020-04-28 20:08:01.996 log_out john
2020-04-28 20:08:02.470 log_in  john
2020-04-28 20:08:03.996 log_out john
2020-04-28 20:08:05.729 log_failed  john
2020-04-29 10:06:45.683 log_in  mark
2020-04-29 10:08:58.299 password_change mark
2020-04-30 14:19:24.921 log_in  jeff
2020-04-30 14:20:31.266 log_out jeff
2020-04-30 14:21:44.438 create_new_user jeff
2020-04-30 14:22:44.455 create_new_user jeff
```

How to write a sql query to count all unique events per day. the unclear part for me is the presence of hours in timestamp. The desired result looks like this:

```
timestamp  count       
2020-04-28 3 
2020-04-29 2
2020-04-30 3
```

Comment: This is heavily dependent on the specific database. What database are you using?

Comment: @TheImpaler clickhouse

Comment: i updated question, it was incorrect

Comment: it's unclear why did you include the column `user` in your question

Answer (score 1):

I think the Clickhouse syntax is:

```
select distinct toDate(timestamp), event
from t;
```

EDIT:

If you want to count the events, use `count(distinct)`:

```
select toDate(timestamp), count(distinct event)
from t
group by toDate(timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table xx(timestamp DateTime64(3), event String, user String) Engine=Memory;
insert into xx values
('2020-04-28 20:07:55.503','log_in', 'john'),
('2020-04-28 20:08:01.996','log_out','john'),
('2020-04-28 20:08:02.470','log_in','john'),
('2020-04-28 20:08:03.996','log_out','john'),
('2020-04-28 20:08:05.729','log_failed','john'),
('2020-04-29 10:06:45.683','log_in','mark'),
('2020-04-29 10:08:58.299','password_change','mark'),
('2020-04-30 14:19:24.921','log_in','jeff'),
('2020-04-30 14:20:31.266','log_out','jeff'),
('2020-04-30 14:21:44.438','create_new_user','jeff'),
('2020-04-30 14:22:44.455','create_new_user','jeff')

SELECT
    toDate(timestamp) AS d,
    uniq(event)
FROM xx
GROUP BY d

┌──────────d─┬─uniq(event)─┐
│ 2020-04-28 │           3 │
│ 2020-04-29 │           2 │
│ 2020-04-30 │           3 │
└────────────┴─────────────┘
```